# Codeigniter - join() returns only one "first table"

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have struggle with codeigniter active record in my model.

Problem is that my query returns only one table, my joined table is missing?

```
    $this->db->select("page.ID, page.TITLE, category.TITLE");
    $this->db->from('page');
    $this->db->join('category','page.ID_CATEGORY = category.ID');
    $query = $this->db->get();

    return $query->result_array();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give unique aliases to your query like array index is unique you can't have two values on same index from your query `TITLE` will become index of array which has records so try below query,your current results in array form will look something like

```
array(
[0] => array(
['ID'] => 1,
['title'] => test page
)
[1] => ...
)
```

Because the column name title is same in your both joined tables,you can't have the array like below one with with 2 values on same index

```
array(
[0] => array(
['ID'] => 1,
['title'] => test page,
['title'] => test cat /* wrong index */
)
[1] => ...
)
```

Query

```
$this->db->select("page.ID, page.TITLE AS page_title, category.TITLE AS cat_title");
$this->db->from('page');
$this->db->join('category','page.ID_CATEGORY = category.ID');
$query = $this->db->get();
```

So resultant array will be look something like

```
array(
[0] => array(
['ID'] => 1,
['page_title'] => test page,
['cat_title'] => test cat,
)
[1] => ...
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
return $query->result();
```

Instead of

```
return $query->result_array();
```

Or try this way:

```
$this->db
        ->select('ID')
        ->from('table2');


$subquery = $this->db->_compile_select();

$this->db->_reset_select(); 

$query  =       $this->db
                    ->select('t1.name')
                    ->from('table1 t1 ')
                    ->join("($subquery)  t2","t2.id = t1.t2_id")
                    ->get('table1 t1');
```

Comment: still same problem.
tnx